# Is it possible to access internal values in a __m128 variable as attribute in a C++ class?

Tags: c++, arrays, attributes

I would like to have a Vector class (which represents vector of 3 floats) implemented with SSE intrinsics (so I will not use the 4th elements of the __m128 type). But I would like to be able to access them easily like attributes : so myVector.x will access the 0-31 bits in vec, myVector.y will access the 32-63 bits in vec, but without having to call some getX() method. The 'x' attribute would be a sort of alias for the 0-31 bits of 'vec'.
Is it possible ?

```
class Vector {  
public:  
  float x;  
  float y;  
  float z;  
private:  
  __m128 vec;  
}
```

Comment: It may be using union :)

Comment: Be careful with unions in this case: Microsoft says, you should not access `__m128` variables directly: http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ayeb3ayc.aspx

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, because this violates the *strong aliasing rule*.

Sure you can use casts or unions to pretend the `__m128` is an array of floats, but the optimizer will not maintain coherency for you, because you're breaking the language's rules.

See [What is the strict aliasing rule?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/98650/103167)

(According to the rule, access using a union is safe, but that only applies when you are naming the union.  Taking a pointer or reference to a union member and then using the pointer or reference directly later is not safe.)

Comment: How the `__m128` and the associated SSE instructions can be useful if you can't access the values of the floats contained in it ?

Comment: @Guillaume: SSE provides store instructions that extract the data to an array of float.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ybhzf6dk.aspx  You should use these store instructions to access components of the `__m128` value, and not try to access its memory directly.

Comment: Won't this destroy the efficiency gained by the use of the SSE instructions ?

Comment: @Guillaume: Design things so you don't convert to and from SSE more often than necessary.  And actually the SSE load/store instructions are about the most efficient memory access method available.  Still, SSE register access is faster, so try to keep things inside SSE as long as possible.

Comment: Shouldn't the answer be something like: "Yes, you can but you shouldn't because this would violate strong aliasing rule" ?

Answer (score 1):

You could perhaps use a *union*, something like

```
union data
{
    float[4] xyz;
    __m128 vec;
} aVec;
```

Then the floats would be `aVec.xyz[0]`, `aVec.xyz[1]`, and `aVec.xyz[2]` and the `__m128` would be `aVec.vec`. The `float` array has four elements here, but nothing says you have to use the fourth one.

Comment: @VJovic Are unions an exception to the strict aliasing rule? I'm using unions each time i need to access the same memory with different interpretation and its working fine with GCC.

Comment: @VJovic Also i found this in the working draft of the c++ standard: *If a standard-layout union contains two or more standard-layout structs that share a common initial sequence,
and if the standard-layout union object currently contains one of these standard-layout structs, it is permitted
to inspect the common initial part of any of them*.

Comment: Is the `union` construction something that _should_ be avoided, but which in fact _works_ with GCC, or bugs can really happen when the program is compiled with full optimization ?

Comment: @Gigi: I elaborated on that at the end of my answer.

Comment: Using g++, you can simply add `--fno-strict-aliasing` and this would work just fine. Given that __m128 isn't exactly part of the standard, maybe platform- and tool-specific answers are just fine here.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a struct which automatically converts to and from `__m128`:

```
struct alignas(16) Vec4f
{
    float x, y, z, w;
    operator __m128() const { return _mm_load_ps(&x);}
    Vec4f(__m128 const v) { _mm_store_ps(&x, v);}
};
```

This has the disadvantage that `Vec4f` would be passed via two SSE registers instead of one (when passed by value: https://godbolt.org/z/sutmuM).

Overall, I'd suggest to rather make a struct which just contains an `__m128` and overload `x()`, `y()`, etc methods. Element-wise operations on SSE registers should be avoided anyway if possible (except using the zeroth element).

N.B.: `alignas(16)` requires C++11, there are compiler-specific alternatives for most compilers. Alternatively, you can use `_mm_loadu_ps` and `_mm_storeu_ps` instead.